# How to color cells based on column value (conditional formatting)

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that contains headers and data, in which I have a column named "city". All of the cells of this column are filled automatically, and the purpose is to color all the cells of the column city dynamically. To proceed I added a new rule, but this is not working.

For example:

```
    -------------
       city
    -------------
        A1
    -------------
        A2
    -------------
        An
    -------------  
        B2
    -------------
        Bn
    -------------
```

Both the column headers and cells values should be colored with blue cyan without using formula.
How should I proceed in order to color the whole column dynamically?

Comment: Column value, or cell value? You want all cells to have the same color, or different colors? Which colors? What formula? Random colors? Automatic colors? Why not just apply a style? Please add the answers to these questions in your original question, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57871268/edit) button.

Comment: @virolino: both the column value and cells, yes the same color the whole column, the color  is blue cyan, without formula , the whole clumn  city,A1,A2,AN, i will update my question ...

Comment: So you want all cells to be blue cyan? If yes, why do you need to do it dynamically? Also, which rule did you add? Which formula? How did it not work?

Comment: yes, because the file is filled automatically based on a template, i don't know exactly the number of rows.

Comment: I think OP is trying to color all non-empty cells in that column. It does not matter the value of the cell, but if the cell has a value or not. Try using a rule based on formula `LEN(A1)>0` Change `A` with the letter of your cities column